# The maximum number of arguments in a Java construcor

Tags: java, android-studio

What is the maximum number of arguments supported in a java constructor.
I am using android studio.
I am getting a too many parameters error when I use above 300 parameters.

Comment: why on earth would you need 300 parameters? it's not Noah's Arc. you don't have to fill all in just one tiny little Object

Comment: *I use above 300 parameters* - WTF, glad I don't have to maintain your code

Comment: @Stultuske Defensive programming?  Maybe the OP expects another Y2K bug at some point? :-)

Comment: Use a property or any other configuration file and read it instead of dealing with 300+ parameters.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen even then. It's not a pokémon game where one constructor has to "catch 'm all" :). Even if all this information is needed for one instantiation, I would believe that it would at least be possible to group some of the data in a composite Object, instead of passing them all seperately

Comment: @Glains usually, parameters are decided by the flow of the application. hard to put into property files what you can't know up forehand

Comment: @Stultuske Actually i tought i have read it was in the `main` method. Of course, then you should think about refactoring your class.

Comment: OP, really interested to know your use-case whereby you need so many.. I usually get irritated if I have around half a dozen

Comment: @AkhilS Could you please provide a use case where you actually need 300 constructor parameters? I'm very curious.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [JVM docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.11):

> The number of method parameters is limited to 255 by the definition of a method descriptor (§4.3.3), where the limit includes one unit for this in the case of instance or interface method invocations.

I guess it's the same with constructors. Either way, your code needs some refactoring to do if it really has a method with over 10 arguments.

Comment: let's assume your opinion on this is shared over methods and constructors. I guess "over 300" qualifies as "over 10" :)

Answer (score -1):

`method( YourCustomObjectContaining301params o301p )` is all you need

Comment: I would not want to maintain a class with 300+ params... (also, does that object have a constructor with 300+ params as well?)

Comment: @Glains not necessarily. setters do work

Comment: @Stultuske Like-wise for the original problem

Comment: @Stultuske Thats why i put it in brackets ;) Anyways, suppose one or more properties are required. Same thing as Springs constructor vs setter injection...

Comment: @ScaryWombat not necessarily so. if all values must be known before termination of instantiation, for instance. A constructor that must log/throw/handle/... an error if not all data is present

Comment: Recursive answer :) @Glains that’s exactly what I meant :)