# Is there a limit in having constructors in a data class? (kotlin)

Tags: kotlin

I've been handling a response that has a large scale of fields particularly almost 7000 fields. I used robopojo to generate a data class out of it. Now i'am getting errors such as overflow so i have to lessen the fields. Eventually the error changed to this

> 04-15 14:25:19.823 17933-17933/com.example.cbc_appraisal D/androidruntime: java.lang.VerifyError: Rejecting class com.example.cbc_appraisal.model.revisedresponse.vacantlot.ValrepLandimpValuationGroupingItem because it failed compile-time verification (declaration of 'com.example.cbc_appraisal.model.revisedresponse.vacantlot.ValrepLandimpValuationGroupingItem' appears in /data/app/com.example.cbc_appraisal-1/base.apk:classes2.dex)

this is my code snip

@Parcelize
data class ValrepLandimpValuationGroupingItem  (

```
@field:SerializedName("valrep_landimp_dos_cml3_total_adjustment")
val valrepLandimpDosCml3TotalAdjustment: String? = null,

@field:SerializedName("valrep_landimp_dos_cml4_contact_no")
val valrepLandimpDosCml4ContactNo: String? = null,

@field:SerializedName("valrep_landimp_dos_dsl1_source")
val valrepLandimpDosDsl1Source: String? = null,

@field:SerializedName("valrep_landimp_dos_dsl3_source")
val valrepLandimpDosDsl3Source: String? = null,

 ... imagine 800 more
```

Im starting to think that kotlin cannot handle many fields. Any suggestion regarding this issue? thank you in advance!!

Comment: 1. Do you *need* `@Parcelize`? That will add a lot of generated code for such a big class and it might be too big to put in a parcel anyway. May be better to just save it as json to a file and parse it later.

Comment: 2. Which json parser do you use for constructing this class from the json data? [Moshi](https://github.com/square/moshi) with a `@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)` may be a good fit since it doesn't use any reflection.

Comment: Sir I'm using @parcelize because im passing it to another intent. If this is the reason why i'm encountering this error, can u suggest me of another work around to pass a big class to another activity thank you!

Comment: since you are already converting to and from json, you can save it as a json string in a file. In the intent then pass only the path to the file, and in the new activity read  that file again and construct this object. If you get the json from a network request it is easiest to just save that response to a file directly.

Comment: hi sir, i already removed the @parcelize and planning to save in in a json file however, im still encountering the Rejected class because it failed compile-time verification. During testing , i tried to lessen this 800 fields to 700 and it worked. I tried adding some more and by the time i reach 750, I encountered again the same error that's why i thought kotlin cannot satisfy having too many fields. this is the behavior that ive been experiencing sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this blog entry](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2018/07/see-whats-coming-in-kotlin-1-3-m1/):

> 255 parameters […] is the practical maximum number of parameters a method can have on the JVM

and (since v1.3) Kotlin can support that number.

The [JVM spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.11) confirms that limit.

I'm not sure whether that limit applies directly to Android too, but [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52325697/the-maximum-number-of-arguments-in-a-java-construcor?noredirect=1&lq=1) suggests it does.  (It also suggests that trying to have anywhere near that number of parameters is a very strong code smell…)

Comment: thank you for the reply, i knew it. however do have any ideas how can i handle this kind of situation? i really have to fetch that data with more than 255 parameters :( its from my company, i already suggested them to optimize the response but they said that its not the best solution they can do right now :(

Comment: Is there no structure within that mass of data?  If there are repeated fields or sections, then they could be broken down to Lists or Arrays; and even if not, I'm sure there's scope for splitting out groups to subobjects.

Comment: @Amoure you don't need a data class where each value is a separate field. It could be stored as a `Map<String, Any>` and looked up by key in runtime. For a HashMap such amounts are absolutely no problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer sirs. I guess i have to test your best suggestions. it did gave me a peace of mind heheh

Comment: On Practice we faced a limit of 124 parameters inside construcor.

Answer (score 1):

No, there's not limit for constructors anywhere, if a limit was present it would violet the concept of constructor overloading.

Ref this for further understanding and syntax:

https://proandroiddev.com/creating-multiple-constructors-for-data-classes-in-kotlin-32ad27e58cac

Also, Welcome to StackOverflow.

**Update**

To handle large amount of fields you can make groups of your fields in JSON format and form a tree structure. That way you can use as many fields as you want with clear conception and code quality.

Comment: Hello sir @Saswata! I just read the documentation you send here and I tried to add the Annotation JVMOverloads and i get this error, 

Backend Internal error: Exception during code generation

btw thank you for entertaining my question. Ive been looking for answers for a month and still cant look for an accurate one. Maybe my question is incorrect. However, i added a code snip on my question sir.

Comment: Hello, due to lack of code previously I had provided you the answer of constructors. As it seems you are dealing with too many fields, refer to @gidds answer. 
Also you can use Objects to group your fields and then use them (Ref: the updated answer). 
And am no Sir. :D

Comment: Hello sir! What I did was i have to split the objects into 2 and make 2 api class with different responses so that i can get the whole response. That's the best solution i did to deal with calls with large responses

Comment: Yes exactly @Amoure